# How can I compare two files based on the value of the first column?

Tags: text-processing, awk, diff, columns, join

I want to compare two files based on the value of their first column:

file1

```
aaa 23 3
bbb 56 6
ccc 45 2
```

file2

```
bbb m a
aaa a m
ccc m m
```

The output file should be:

```
aaa  a m
bbb  m a
ccc  m m
```

i.e., we need to print the 2nd and 3rd columns of the 2nd file with the first column order of first file.

Can anybody suggest an awk script for this?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next};{print a[$1]}' file2 file1
```

Comment: thank u... the code is working... i made little modifications to get the proper result....thank u so much

Answer (score 1):

This will be very slow for large files, but you could do

```
$ while read a rest; do grep -w $a file2; done < file1
aaa a m
bbb m a
ccc m m
```

A faster way, in Perl:

```
$ cat file1 | perl -lane '$k{$F[0]}=$_;
                END{
                  open(A,"file1");
                  while(<A>){/^(.+?)\s/; print $k{$1}}
               }' file2
aaa a m
bbb m a
ccc m m
```